# Можно ли по событию клика в java script перезаписать значение глобальной переменной?

Tags: javascript, jquery, события

Всех приветствую! Подскажите пожалуйста как лучше поступить?
В моем коде есть глобальная переменная, в которую записывается результат исполнения функции, который является объектом. params = windowparams(); Так же он пересчитывается при изменении размеров окна (resize). Появилась необходимость персчитывать параметры при клике на определенный элемент, так как в этот момент изменяется высота одного из блоков, и ее нужно изменить в params. У меня были 2 идеи: либо привязаться к событию клика, но так как на клик или онклик я могу только вызвать функцию, а перезаписать переменную глобальную не могу, с этим событием не получается. Второй вариант это изменение размера блока, но тоже не могу понять как произвести такую операцию. Я не очень знаю js, поэтому прошу помощи у вас. Спасибо.

Comment: "перезаписать переменную глобальную не могу" - ??

Answer (score 0):

Присвоить значение переменной

```
let params = windowparams();
//...
button.onclick = function(){
   params = windowparams();
}
```

Изменить размер блока

```
let element = document.getElementById("id_элемента");
let width = "500px";
button.onclick = function(){
       element.style.width = width;
    }
```